# How to export 16-bit HEIF images in Swift?

Tags: swift, core-image, bit-depth, heif

I am trying to write an export function for my app that allows 16-bit depth HEIF files. Apple's documentation doesn't specify whether 16-bit is supported nor if the `writeHEIFRepresentation()` method requires any specific option for that. I have been trying with a 16-bit per color (64-bits per pixel) format and either the extended Display P3 or the HLG color spaces, but the output is still 8-bits. The source image is a 16-bits TIFF.

This is my playground code:

```swift
import Cocoa
import CoreImage

let originalImageURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: "/Users/myself/Desktop/DSC00990-HDR-3.tif")
let exportedImageURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: "/Users/myself/Desktop/DSC00990-HDR.heic")
guard let colorSpace = CGColorSpace(name: CGColorSpace.displayP3) else {
    print("Couldn't create a color space. :(")
    exit(1)
}
let context = CIContext()
let options = [kCGImageDestinationLossyCompressionQuality as CIImageRepresentationOption: 1.0 as CGFloat]

guard let image = CIImage(contentsOf: originalImageURL) else {
    print("Couldn't create an image. :(")
    exit(1)
}

do {
    _ = try context.writeHEIFRepresentation(of: image, to: exportedImageURL, format: CIFormat.RGBA16, colorSpace: colorSpace, options: options)
    print("It worked")
}
catch {
    print("It failed.")
}
```

Would any of you have experience with creating HEIF files on CoreImage to share, please? Perhaps Apple's encoder doesn't support 16-bit HEIF files yet?

Thank you so much in advance.

Comment: You’ve misunderstood the docs. This is not a depth image. You are writing in 8 bit because your format is ABGR8.

Comment: Yes, I did. As I mentioned the docs aren't clear. This is what depthImage's documentation looks like. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coreimage/ciimagerepresentationoption/2902268-depthimage

Comment: You are right, though. That colorspace is indeed 8-bit. However, using CIFormat.RGBA16 makes no difference either.

Comment: The docs are perfectly clear if you know what a depth image is. I’m sorry my format idea isn’t helpful but the depth image is another matter entirely.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you are trying to achieve. Does the `.tif` file contain a depth image already? Are you trying to export _only_ the depth image or add it to another image?

Comment: `CIImageRepresentation.depthImage` is actually used to attach a _separate_ depth image to an image when writing it into the HEIC file (so the file would contain both). You may want to check out this session from last year's WWDC (they speak about the `portraitEffectsMatt`, but it handles the same): https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2018-503/?time=300

Comment: Thank you very much for your comments. I will update my question to make it clearer based on your suggestions.

Comment: Matt, Preview shows 16-bit as an option for HEIC exports and macOS supports 16-bit on other image formats. However, I couldn't find any document from Apple stating limitations on their HEIC encoder. So maybe they will force everything down to 8-bit.

Comment: Frank, thank you for the explanation and the URL! I will check it out.

Comment: There is a misunderstanding in the Preview export. It will show 10-bit/12-bit/16-bit - or whatever value is the source format. It doesn't mean it can save in that format.

Answer (score 0):

```
if #available(macOS 12.0, *) {
                    try ciContext.writeHEIF10Representation(of: processImage, to: destUrl, colorSpace: colorSpace, options: options)
                }
```

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coreimage/cicontext/3762900-writeheif10representation

Comment: A little more explanation of "why this code" and "why does this work" would be helpful, along with "this was documented at X".

Comment: Surely, surely self explanatory ?  And Google is your friend, but for you the link above.

Comment: Oh and HEIF doesn't do 16 bit as far as I am aware it does 10bit as per the API above.

Comment: This answer was flagged as "low quality" and I was hoping to help you rescue it.

Comment: This answer does not answer question which is about 16 bit. Not 10 bit